# How to block specific UIViewcontroller for landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to block LandscapeRight orientation for some specific UIViewControllers in my app. But its not working. My app supports auto layout as well as "landscape right" and "Portrait" orientation.

Here is code that I am trying. Am I missing anything?

```
-   (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
  }
-   (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Are your view controllers the _top-level_ view controllers? If they are in a UINavigationController interface, for example, they are not - so they have no say in the app orientation.

Comment: Yes I am using navigation controller

Comment: Well, that's what you're missing.

Comment: So what exactly I need to do

Comment: You need to face reality and understand how orientation works. You can't force different orientations for different pushed/popped view controllers. Only top-level view controllers can force orientation change. Your pushed/popped view controllers are not top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level view controller is in charge of app orientation. You are in a navigation interface. Thus, the UINavigationController, not your child UIViewController, is top-level, so it is consulted as to the app orientation. Your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is never even called. Use the UINavigationControllerDelegate method `navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: Out of interest, if you were to subclass UInavigationController and write a bit of code that allowed control over orientation, base on the topViewController object; could it be done?

Comment: What you're describing is not supported. This issue has been done to death here on Stack Overflow. Please just do a search. There is no need to ask this same question again.

Comment: Its not something I have any interest in doing. Was just curious thats all. Don't need the implementation details.

Comment: I forgot to mention: you can certainly use the UINavigationControllerDelegate to state your supported interface orientations. But you cannot _change_ this to _force_ rotation while pushing and popping.